# trouble working with images and pixel values in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, bgi

I have 9 pictures all of a person but he is standing in a different spot for each of the 9 pictures.  The first nested for loop creates a triple array where j=picture and x and y represent the coordinates of the pixels in each picture.  I use the getpixel function to store them in this triple loop.  My problem lies within the second nested for loop.  I create an arrays for the rgb values of each pixel than bubble sort them to find the median value.  In theory this should return an image where the man has disappeared and just the background of the photo remains.  However it is not working and still displays the picture of with the man in it.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  #include <iostream>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <ctime>
   #include <graphics.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   using namespace std;

void loadImage(int imageNumber);
void bubbleSort(arr[], int n);

int main()
{
    //triple array to work with all 9 pics
    int picture[9][200][225];

    int redArray[9];
    int greenArray[9];
    int blueArray[9];

    //size of the 3 arrays to be used in bubble sort
    int n1=sizeof(redArray);
    int n2=sizeof(greenArray);
    int n3=sizeof(blueArray);

    //window that displays the picture
    initwindow(600, 625, "tourist");


    //stores the pixel value for all 9 pictures
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
    {
        loadImage(j);
        {
            for(int x=0; x<200; x++)
            {
                for(int y=0; y<225; y++)
                {   
                    picture[j][x][y]=getpixel(x, y);
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    //sets the rgb values of all the pixels of all the pictures  and bubble sorts them
    //using the median value of 9 elements(4th value) to remove the person from the picture
    for(int x=0; x<200; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<225; y++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
            {


                redArray[j]=RED_VALUE(picture[j][x][y]);
                greenArray[j]=GREEN_VALUE(picture[j][x][y]);
                blueArray[j]=BLUE_VALUE(picture[j][x][y]);
            }


            bubbleSort(redArray[], n1);
            bubbleSort(greenArray[], n2);
            bubbleSort(blueArray[], n3);

            //putpixel redarray[4]
            putpixel(x,y,Color(redArray[4], greenArray[4], blueArray[4]);

        }   
    }

    getch();    
}

//this is a BGI function that loads the image onto the current window
void loadImage(int imageNumber)
{
     char str[5];
     sprintf(str, "%i.jpg", imageNumber);
     readimagefile(str,0,0,200,225); 
}

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }   


    }  

}
```

Comment: Can you not use `std::sort`?

Comment: Also, can you show the input and output?

Comment: `sprintf` appends a null character; I think you need `char str[6];`.

Comment: Wait a minute... It "still displays the picture of with the man in it"? You have nine pictures with the man, which one does it display?

Comment: -no it has to be bubble sort

Comment: -it loops through all 9 pictures than sits on the last one

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: theres problems with passing the arr[] and int n in the bubblesort function as well as Color not declared in putpixel line

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
int n1=sizeof(redArray);
```

sets n1 to be the size of 9 integers, which is probably 36 (depending on your machine architecture)

You are then using this as an input to your bubble sort, which means your bubble sort is going way outside the array boundaries. This is undefined behavior and may lead to the values in the arrays being incorrect.

Change the lines to

```
int n1=sizeof(redArray) / sizeof (redArray[0]);
```

or even just use `9` as you have that in several other places as well (maybe you could define a `const int` as 9 so you can easily change it later.